# how to position a div, in body with 100% width, with same left and right space?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with `position:relativ` (doesnt metter here I can set it to absolute as well) I want to place my `<div>` space on left and right side with 20px but the `width:` have to be `100%`. I am giving my codes and you can see how it seems for now with `margin: 0 20px 0 20px`

*(please dont delete the question, I have already tried the similar question sorry :/ )*

->> Second question if should I make a `<div>` container so it includes everything? or is it cleaver to make how I did?

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<body>
<!-- <div class="container"> -->
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="">INFO</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ME</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <div class="daily">
    </div>
    <div class="aussen">
     ...
```

**MY CSS CODE**

```
body {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #EFEFFB;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

.navbar {

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.navbar ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.navbar ul li {

    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 0px;

}


.navbar ul li a {

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar ul li:hover {

    background: #585858;

}

.daily {

    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px


}
```

how it looks like now as picture: 
[image]

so the space on left is okay but I want the same on right as well. What is wrong with my code?
- accepting suggestions for improvement as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As easy as that :* In your `.css` file, just remove one thing from `.daily` class :

```
width:100%; // remove that and your margin will apply correctly left/right
```

So your daily class should be like:

```
.daily {
position: relative;
top: 70px;
height: 110px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt worked so my new .daily class is like that:  .daily {

 position: relative;
 top: 70px;
 height: 110px;
/* width: 100%;*/
 border: 1px solid black; }

Comment: Yes it does work, I tried it myself. See my edit for full code of `daily` class : you forgot the margin in your code in the comment you made above.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Don't forget to mark my answer as correct one or upvote it, as you want :)

Comment: hey @stacks do you know, how I can do this for position:absolute divs? I like to use absolute more and have trouble with relativ with another div im working for atm..

Comment: @CihanDincel Hm maybe you should ask this question on another topic on SO with your code and if you send me the link to this topic I will answer you there :)

Comment: Hello @stacks sure I created here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316649/how-to-position-a-div-with-positionabsolute-in-body-with-100-width-with-same

Comment: I was wanting to help but you already got your answer, so that's fine I guess! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an inner `div` and `padding` on the outer `div` to achieve what you want:

```css
.daily {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.inner {
  height: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="daily">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I saw know :) I marked the one which was easiest to me. But upvoted everyone becouse it was helpfull. I hope its so okay

Comment: Thanks for help :).. What do you mean think about my second question. Is it better to set a div which includes everythink or is it like this good as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212021/discussion-between-cihan-dincel-and-anurag-srivastava).

Comment: Unless you want to do an action on the whole page, there's no need for it

Comment: @ Anurag Srivastava may I ask how can I do this for position:absolute divs as well? couldnt do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div className='daily-container'>
  <div className="daily">
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.daily-container {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.daily {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```