# how to position a div with position:absolute, in body with 100% width, with same left and right space?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with **`position:absolute`**  I want to place my `<div>` space on left and right side with 20px but the `width:` have to be `100%`. I am giving my codes and you can see how it seems for now with `margin: 0 20px 0 20px` But if possible without creating anyother inner or out `<div`. Is there a way for that or do I have to creat another `<div>` ?

*(please dont delete the question, I have already tried the similar question sorry :/ )*

```css
.navbar {

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.navbar ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.navbar ul li {

    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 0px;

}


.navbar ul li a {

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar ul li:hover {

    background: #585858;

}

.daily {

    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px


}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="">INFO</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ME</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <div class="daily">
    </div>
    <div class="aussen">
```

so the space on left is okay but I want the same on right as well. What is wrong with my code?
- accepting suggestions for improvement as well :)

Comment: try   display: flex; to main div

Comment: What is having an incorrect width? `.navbar`, `.daily`, or `.aussen`?
`.daily` is having `position: relative;`
`.navbar` have got no margins

Comment: @Palak Jadav I dont have main div this div is on my body

Comment: hello @Javascript Dev what do you mean with incorrect? everything going fine with codes but if i want a margin from left and right 20px it doesnt work for my absolute div

Comment: yeah i changed the relativ its absolute. A want margin to .daily from left and right 20px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.daily {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Its working but I want the position absolute not relative

Comment: Ok... I'll fix it.

Comment: I am fine with absolute, becouse I want blace something in this .daily div and if I use relative for that .daily its harder to place them in the future

Comment: nice! that worked. But why, why should i remove my widht?

Comment: The `left` and `right` are automatically stretching this div.

Comment: @CihanDincel `div` is a `block` element so it default stretches the width to full no need to provide the width for these. But I am still thinking why you want to set to `absolute for this div.

Comment: @Manjuboyz isnt it better to position absolute the out divs? I mean isnt it easier to place inner divs after that with relative? or am i thinking totaly wrong?

Comment: I mean isnt it hard to position relativ div to a relativ div than relativ div to absolute div?

Comment: yeah, You can use absolute and keeping parent as relative.

Comment: so wait :) which one is better; a absolute parent div and a relativ child (like here) or relativ parent and a relativ child?

Comment: It all depends on requirement, ideally Parent can have relative and child will have absolute properties w.r.t parent, so hence in your case it works good

Comment: so I tried every confuguration.. What you say is better I mean the parents to set relativ is better. But can you give me an example when should I use a Parent as absolute? or is it better everytime to use a parent div as relativ?